# Double quotes as a 'function' (verbatim ToString?)

Tags: functions, function-construction, evaluation, notebooks, string-manipulation

Can we construct a function `F` such that **F makes any typed text into a string**.
Just like double quotes.

```
In[1]  F[var=3]
Out[1] var=3 (* as a string *)
```

Or can we construct a function `G` such that **G makes any input or output into a string**.

```
In[2] x=3+3+3
Out[2] 9
In[3] G[In[2]]
Out[3] x=3+3+3 (* as a string *)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also do something like this:

```
SetAttributes[ExpressionString, HoldAll];
ExpressionString[expr_] := ToString[Unevaluated[expr]]
```

This gives:

```
ExpressionString[x = 3 + 3]
(*"x = 3 + 3"*)
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry I was too late to comment.

Answer (score 3):

One possible way

[image: Mathematica graphics]

code

```
f[x_] := ToString[x]
f[HoldForm[var = 3]] 
f[HoldForm[x = 3 + 3 + 3]]
```

Need to use `HoldForm` around the argument you pass to the function to prevent Mathematica from evaluating before it reaches the function.

I do not know if there is way to avoid this. But may be there is.